# Passing a value to the next frame

Tags: php, html

I am currently having a problem about passing the value.
I need to design a online grocery store website which is divided into three frames(left,top right and bottom right). It's like the user clicks on the item he wants to know in the image map on the left, and the id of that product is passed to the top right frame where I use php to connect to mysql database and display the relative row. Then the user clicks on the "add" button which should pass the id value to the bottom right frame for purchase purpose. But something goes wrong here. 
After searching the database, I have the codes below that prints a table as well as a button to pass the value to the bottom right frame.

```
    if ($num_rows > 0) {
      print "<table bgcolor='#33FFFF' border='3' summary='products in store' width='80%' align='center'>";
      print "<tr>\n";
      print "<td>Product ID</td>";
      print "<td>Prodcut Name</td>";
      print "<td>Unit Price</td>";
      print "<td>Unit Quantity</td>";
      print "<td>In Stock</td>";
      print "</tr>";

      print "<tr>\n";
  print "<td>$row[product_id]</td>";
  print "<td>$row[product_name]</td>";
  print "<td>$row[unit_price]</td>";
  print "<td>$row[unit_quantity]</td>";
  print "<td>$row[in_stock]</td>";
  print "</tr>";
      print "</table>";

echo '
<div>
<form action=“bottom_right.php” method="get" target="bottom_right">
<input name="id" value="'.$product_id.'">
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
</div>';
}
```

For the testing purpose, I have the code below for the bottom_right frame to verify if the product id has been passed.

```
<body>
<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
echo "aaa";
 ?>
```

It turns out that the original appearance of the bottom right frame is "aaa" in text, but after I click on the "add" button in the top right frame, it becomes "url not found".

Anyone could help me figure out what I did wrong or what I have missed?
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I see something wrong with the quotes symbol here;

```
<form action=“bottom_right.php” method="get" target="bottom_right">
```

the quotes of `“bottom_right.php”` looks different. Kindly correct this and try.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just found it!! That's exactly what goes wrong!!!

Comment: you're welcome. :) Kindly consider voting and accepting my answer, if it helped you.